# Unable to run super-AND repository in JupyterLab

Tags: pytorch, python-3.7, jupyter-lab

I am trying to run this [repository](https://github.com/super-AND/super-AND) in JupyterLab. I am getting below error, while running this command python3 main.py --dataset cifar10 --network resnet18. For installation setup i just followed the steps mentioned in the github link.

Log:

```
Downloading https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz to ./data/cifar-10-python.tar.gz

100.0%Extracting ./data/cifar-10-python.tar.gz to ./data

Files already downloaded and verified

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 237, in <module>

    main()

  File "main.py", line 215, in main

    train(r, epoch, net, trainloader, optimizer, npc, criterion, criterion2, ANs_discovery, args.device)

  File "main.py", line 124, in train

    features = net(inputs) # (256, 128)

  File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__

    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/home/jovyan/super-AND/models/resnet_cifar.py", line 111, in forward

    out = self.layer2(out)

  File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__

    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 100, in forward

    input = module(input)

  File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__

    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/home/jovyan/super-AND/models/resnet_cifar.py", line 26, in forward

    out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))

  File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 914, in relu

    result = torch.relu(input)

  File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/signal_handling.py", line 66, in handler

    _error_if_any_worker_fails()
```